# Vector Autoregression with constrained variables

Tags: vector-autoregression

Assume we have 3 time-series variables $Y$, $W$, and $P$. They are positive and co-integrated with $0 < W + P < Y$ at any time $t$.

Now define $w = W/Y$, $p = P/Y$, and $c = 1 - w - p$.

Also define some latent variable driving $Y$, for instance we care about $Z$ with $Y = Z * X$, where $Z$ is stationary and $X$ is co-integrated with $Y$.

Now, I want to understand how $Z$ is related with $w$ and $p$.

I perform some univariate regressions:
I find that $\Delta w$ depends on $\Delta log Z$ with positive coefficient.
I find that $\Delta p$ depends on $\Delta log Z$ with negative coefficient.
I find that $\Delta c$ does not depend on $\Delta log Z$.

My question is does it makes sense to estimate a VAR for $\Delta w$, $\Delta p$, and $\Delta \log Z$?

How does the constraint $0 < W + P < Y$ affect my results? How do I account for it?

Should I impose long-run restrictions (given $W,$ $P$, and $Y$ are co-integrated)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this coming from macroeconomics with $Y$ being the GDP, $P$ the price level and $W$...?

Comment: Yes and not, Y is GDP and P and W are GDP components. Can you help me?

Comment: What components are those? Probably it does not affect the statistical aspects of the question, but it would be nice to know the interpretation. Maybe you could include a small paragraph on the interpretation of these things. (But I don't think it's crucial.)

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted I like the question.